# Tiny C# library to tell whether Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS

Tags: library, c#

I need a very small C# library that would tell me on what operating system my C# program is running.

I don't need the OS version number, just something very general, for instance I would be happy with one of:

```
Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS
```

Requirements:

- Open Source, ideally Public Domain
- Downloadable easily as DLL

None of the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138040/how-to-detect-properly-windows-linux-mac-operating-systems are robust+easy enough.

Answer (score 5):

[C# itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(v=vs.110).aspx) actually provides a method to detect what operating system you are running at a basic level. All of the OS' it can detect can be found in the link. Is this what you were looking for?

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
PlatformID     pid = os.Platform;
switch (pid) 
    {
    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
    case PlatformID.Win32S:
    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
    case PlatformID.WinCE:
        Console.WriteLine("I'm on windows!");
        break;
    case PlatformID.Unix:
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a linux box!");
        break;
    case PlatformID.MacOSX:
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a mac!");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("No Idea what I'm on!");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Apparently the value is sometimes Unix even for MacOS though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138040 (linked from my question too)

Comment: @Nicolas Raou: That's because OSX I Unix, too.

Comment: @StefanSteiger While it is technically true, such a value is not as informative as what the question asks for. If there is a `PlatformID.MacOSX` then a solution that gives `PlatformID.MacOSX` for all MacOS systems would be better.